# Bot composer - Unable to Begin new Dialog after Cancel All active dialog

Tags: chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I am using Bot Composer.
I want to cancel all dialogs at some point but then begin a new Dialog. Any solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should put the Cancel all active dialogs after your Begin a new dialog.

I know it doesn't make sense to put it after but it works.